# Adding text (just text!) to a form in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, api, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms

OK, I finally figured out how to add (or edit) form controls through the `form API` in Drupal.

But now, I would like to add text to a form. Not a `<textarea>`, and not a `<textfield>`; both of which can be edited by the user. I would like to add `<p>static text</p>`, written by me, to be read by the user.

How would one do that?

Comment: Belongs on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can do this using [`#markup`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#markup-attribute):

```
$form['some_text'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<p>Some text</p>'
);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `#type` line isn't necessary if you are using render arrays. But it doesn't hurt to keep it in there.

Comment: @theunraveler: Yep you're right I just put it in there for demonstration

Comment: The default type in Drupal 7 is "markup", not "item" as used in this answer. If you want to use "item", you need to explicitly set `#type`.

Comment: Also, for really short strings, or passing in a variable with markup in it, you can get by with `$form['some_text']['#markup'] = 'HTML';`, saving two lines of code :)

Comment: I found people suggesting using prefix or suffix on an element before or after the desired markup, but this is clearly the best option

Comment: This adds a <p> inside the submit button container widget of my views exposed form, which is not what I want.

Comment: But this is: $form['#prefix'] = '<p>Some text</p>';

Comment: Is this supposed to go in template.php? It doesn't seem to do anything. I'm using correct form ID (replacing - with _ but still nothing at all)